# Viewmodel executes init after updating a MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

whenever I try to update a mutable state flow (uiState), the code in the init of the viewModel executes again (and hence the uiState resets).

This only happens if I use any info related to the previous state of the uiState (at least that's why I think given the following code).

The Code:

```
init {
        Log.d("Error log", "init again")
    }

    private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<CreateGameState> =
        MutableStateFlow(
            CreateGameState.InputDataState(
                selectedHeroes = listOf(),
                selectedVillain = null,
                selectedEncounters = listOf(),
            )
        )
    val uiState: StateFlow<CreateGameState> = _uiState

    fun onAction(action: CreateGameActions) {
        when (action) {
            is CreateGameActions.SelectHero -> {
                when (_uiState.value) {
                    is CreateGameState.InputDataState -> {
                        _uiState.update {
                            /* this line causes the error */(it as CreateGameState.InputDataState).copy(selectedHeroes = it.selectedHeroes.plusElement(action.hero))
                         /* this line doesn't cause error */(it as CreateGameState.InputDataState).copy(selectedHeroes = listOf(Hero.SPIDERMAN))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when only executing the line that causes the error, the Log of the `init` function is shown in Logcat again.
With this, I loose the uiState and my app gets stuck on the initial state always.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: The error is in something you’re doing outside this class. The init block can only be called once on an instance, so you must be somehow creating new instances of your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tenfour04 was right.
I turns out I was injecting the viewModel in a composable with the constructor as a default parameter. Recomposition was causing the creation of a new ViewModel.

Simply by injecting the same instance of the viewModel solved it.